# Why is windows remote desktop switching window sizes to ultra wide? Is there a way outside of reboot to fix it?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

There is no doubt that this is a bug.  I am just wondering if anyone has any knowledge about the root cause, or perhaps a way short of reboot to fix it.

Relevant bits o information:

- Occurs in Windows 10 x86 (VM)
- Occurs in Windows 11 arm64 (VM)
- Windows 11 arm64 install has been running for a week with 3 pieces of software installed (Visual studio, SSMS, git for windows)
- VMs are only ever accessed via remote desktop
- RDP client is Microsoft RD on Mac or Microsoft RD on Android
- Mac RDP Client is directed to use multiple monitors
- Rebooting windows fixes the problem until it occurs again
- Seems like it occurs more often if I connect from Android and then the next connection is from Mac (screen sizes, count issue perhaps)
- But sometimes it occurs even if I haven't connected from Android
- Mac laptop, so 2 different monitor sizes

Sometimes when I log in all or most windows will suddenly resize to be ultra wide.  They resist efforts to shrink them in the horizontal direction, and if I successfully do manage to set a sane size, the window helpfully reverts to the ultra wide size.  The title bars are screwed up and grabbing the windows to move them makes them disappear.  The ALTF4 size option makes them disappear.  And when I say ultra wide, I mean thousands and thousands of pixels wide, like 4-8 times the width of my bigger monitor.

The terms are all so generic that search is useless on google, duckduckgo and stackxxx.  I would be deeply grateful if anyone has suggestions.  I have been burning a few minutes at a time on this for a while now to no avail, and it is making me grumpy.

Comment: Does ending _Desktop Windows Manager_ in Task Manager resolve the issue upon initiating an RDP session? _(e.g. initiate RDP session, immediately end Desktop Windows Manager - does the issue then reoccur during the same session?)_

Comment: @JW0914 thanks for the suggestion, I just rebooted my windows 11 the other day, I will try that at and ping you here with the result when it next happens.

Comment: @JW0914 It has been a long time, I don't think it happened until now.  No rhyme or reason, I see it happened today.  There were 2 dwm.exe processes, I killed one and all the windows got normal sized, but as soon as I moved them, they became super wide again.  Unfortunately killing dwm.exe left a white space on the screen that covers everything, so reboot it is.